# Shift elements to right in array

Tags: algorithm

I have an exercise which gives you an input of array and want you to shift all elements to right one time.

```
Input         |       Output
1 2 3 4       |       4 1 2 3
```

How can I do that?
Code is not required just algorithm will be enough.
  Only thing i have tried(`n` is length of array)

```
for (int i = 0; i <n/2; ++i)
    {
        swap(ar[i],ar[i+1]);
    }
```

Comment: @kraskevich I edited my question and added what I have tried

Comment: Where does `n/2` comes from in your code? The idea to swap adjacent elements in some order is correct.

Comment: @beaker I have tried that to,it worked not

Comment: @kraskevich just a try to solve the problem

Comment: @beaker it is not homework:)

Comment: It seems you are in search of an algorithm. Pretend you are the computer, following step-by-step instructions to accomplish this. What steps would you give yourself to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of swapping adjacent elements is correct. You need to go through all of them, not the first half. Something like:

```
for i = n - 2 downto 0
    swap(a[i], a[i + 1])
```

would work.

Comment: did you test it before posting?

Comment: @user7387102 I didn't run the code. However, it's easy to prove it's correctness.

Comment: well I did and unfortunately answer was different

Comment: @user7387102 You did it wrong then. I've just tested it and it works properly. Note: both `n - 2` and `0` are inclusive bounds.

Comment: Thanks for thy heuristic answer!